# SCALA : Read the text file and create tuple of it

Tags: scala, apache-spark, tuples

How to create a tuple from the below-existing RDD?

```
// reading a text file "b.txt" and creating RDD 
val rdd = sc.textFile("/home/training/desktop/b.txt")
```

b.txt dataset -->

```
 Ankita,26,BigData,newbie
 Shikha,30,Management,Expert
```

Comment: what are your expected tuples? give some samples. :)

Comment: expected tuple --((Ankita,26,BigData,newbie), (Shikha,30,Management,Expert))

Comment: you want arrays of tuples right?

Comment: yeah .. that will also go fine :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are intending to have `Array[Tuples4]` then you can do the following

```
scala> val rdd = sc.textFile("file:/home/training/desktop/b.txt")
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = file:/home/training/desktop/b.txt MapPartitionsRDD[5] at textFile at <console>:24

scala> val arrayTuples = rdd.map(line => line.split(",")).map(array => (array(0), array(1), array(2), array(3))).collect
arrayTuples: Array[(String, String, String, String)] = Array((" Ankita",26,BigData,newbie), (" Shikha",30,Management,Expert))
```

Then you can access each fields as `tuples`

```
scala> arrayTuples.map(x => println(x._3))
BigData
Management
res4: Array[Unit] = Array((), ())
```

**Updated**

If you have variable sized input file as

```
Ankita,26,BigData,newbie
Shikha,30,Management,Expert
Anita,26,big
```

you can write match case pattern matching as

```
scala> val arrayTuples = rdd.map(line => line.split(",") match {
     | case Array(a, b, c, d) => (a,b,c,d)
     | case Array(a,b,c) => (a,b,c)
     | }).collect
arrayTuples: Array[Product with Serializable] = Array((Ankita,26,BigData,newbie), (Shikha,30,Management,Expert), (Anita,26,big))
```

**Updated again**

As @eliasah pointed that above procedure is a bad practice which is using `product iterator`. As his suggestion we should know the maximum elements of the input data and use following logic where we assign default values for no elements

```
val arrayTuples = rdd.map(line => line.split(",")).map(array => (Try(array(0)) getOrElse("Empty"), Try(array(1)) getOrElse(0), Try(array(2)) getOrElse("Empty"), Try(array(3)) getOrElse("Empty"))).collect
```

And as @philantrovert pointed out, we can verify the output in the following way, if we are not using `REPL`

```
arrayTuples.foreach(println)
```

which results to

```
(Ankita,26,BigData,newbie)
(Shikha,30,Management,Expert)
(Anita,26,big,Empty)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. And can we create an array dynamically depending on the no: of columns which are different for different rows.

Comment: please see my updated answer :) and thanks for upvote and acceptance :)

Comment: checked the updated answer too ..Thanks a ton Ramesh .. I learned new things from you .:)))

Comment: great to hear that :)

Comment: Infering Product is a bad practice @RameshMaharjan . Personally I'd go with a default value (maybe null or an empty string) instead and keep it as a tuple 4

Comment: You can also use `foreach` with `println`. Not saying `map` is wrong, but it's a nice practice to use `foreach` to denote that this piece of code has a side effect.

Comment: @eliasah, thanks for your suggestions. I have edited my answer according to your suggestions :) I hope the answer is good now

Comment: Looks great ! +1

Comment: @philantrovert, thanks for your suggestion. I have included your suggestion in my answer :) I hope the answer is good